# Json deserializing with file that contains more than 300 classes

Tags: android, json, api, kotlin, retrofit2

i am creating an app that reads some info from api about many countries, using Retrofit2. I can use the plugin to automatically create classes based on json file but it generates something like 350+ data classes. Can I do it in any other way? Or that number of classes is necessary?

Json contains "countries" node that has got 350+ country children like "Afganistan", "Boliwia" etc

Comment: Do all of the values have same data structure?

Comment: Could you please add short example of yours Json?

Answer (score 0):

you must change the structure of your API response that sends information of each country as a JSONArray object instead of JSONObject with the key set to the country name.

like this :

```
[
      {
           name : "Afganistan",
           people : 12334,
           ...
      },
      ...,
 ]
```

Comment: That's an open source API, not mine.

Comment: This is a suggestion rather than an answer

Comment: @wikktamm if the received response by API is a set of JSON objects with key set to the country name I think you must create a data class for each JSON object. This link may be helpful for you -> https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all

Comment: @MohammadNouri its really not scalable because class of defined definition represent objects, creating classes with same properties but just different name is not a very good practise :)

Answer (score 0):

If all the countries are compatible with the same data-representation, then you can just create a class which holds all the information in it:

```kotlin
class Country(val countryName: String, val prop: String, val otherprop: OtherType, ...)

fun JSONObject.toCountryWith(name: String) =
    Country(name, getString["prop"], ...)
```

You may create a JSONObject of the json first, and then iteratre over it creating the list of Country:

```kotlin
val list = mutableListOf<Country>()

JSONObject(yourJsonString).apply {
    for(key in keys()) {
        list.add(getJsonObject(key).toCountryWith(key))
    }
}

// list is ready with objects of Country
```